# Where do you get graphics drivers for an Asus X202E?

Tags: graphics, games

Everything works great except when I try playing games. I get the same problem with Kerbal Space Program (not Steam) and Armello (Steam). The problem is whenever the game is open the cursor constantly flickers. I've tried full screen and windowed mode.

There are no additional drivers in the Additional Drivers section of Software & Updates. My cpu is Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-3217U CPU @ 1.80GHz.

lshw -c video:

```
*-display               
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 09
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:26 memory:f7800000-f7bfffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

Comment: Please determine the video driver in use by running `lshw -c video`.  Edit your question to include the results.

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: It appears you have the correct driver.  There is some configuration info here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/intel_graphics